# flutter rendering issue when add to widgets to stack

Tags: flutter, rendering

I am working with Flutter and getting a rendering issue when adding slider widget to stack children.
the stack children are Slider , ListView and container.
if I removed the Slider it works perfectly but when I add the slider widget it crash the listView widget and getting the following error message

> ======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
> The following assertion was thrown during paint():
> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#00b88 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

here is my code

stack code :

```
 Stack(
          children: [
            SliderScreen(),
            Positioned(top: 210, left: 0, child: ProductsScreen()),
            Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                child: Container(
                  child: Contact(),
                ))
          ],
        )
```

slider screen :

```
return ImageSlideshow(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 200,
  initialPage: 0,
  indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
  indicatorBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
  children: [
    Image.asset(
      'assets/images/slider/image1.png',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    Image.asset(
      'assets/images/slider/image2.jpg',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    Image.asset(
      'assets/images/slider/image3.jpg',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ],
  autoPlayInterval: 3000,
);
```

products screen :

```
 return Obx(()=>productsController.productsList.isEmpty
    ? Center(
  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
)
    : ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: productsController.productsList.length,
    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ProductCard(
        product: productsController.productsList[index],
        increaseByOne: () {
          productsController.increaseByOne(index);
        },
        decreaseByOne: () {
          productsController.decreaseByOne(index);
        }))
);
```

contact screen :

```
return InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30, left: 5, right: 5),
    child: Card(
      elevation: 0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
      // shadowColor: Colors.black,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        side: const BorderSide(
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: 1.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'infonumber',
              ),
              // LocaleText('orcontactat'),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5.0,
              ),
              Text(
                "8888888888",
              ),
            ]),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```